# How to sum values of the same key in a dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, sum, key-value

Supose my dictionary: `mydict = [{"red":6}, {"blue":5}, {"red":12}]`

This is what I've done so far:

```
for key, value in mydict() :
    if key == mydict.keys():
        key[value] += value
    else:
        print (key, value)
```

I don't think I'm getting it quite right (been stuck for hours), but I want the output to look like this:

```
blue 5
red 18
```

or

```
red 18
blue 5
```

Comment: A dictionary has only one value per key. If you do `mydict = {"red":6, "blue":5, "red":12}`, then print `mydict`, you will see only the last value for "red".

Comment: OK, so now `mydict` is a list of single-item dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not recommend this since it results a messy design:

```
class MyDict(dict):

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key in self:
            super().__setitem__(key, self[key] + value)
        else:
            super().__setitem__(key, value)

>>> d = MyDict({'red': 6, 'blue': 5})
>>> d['red'] = 12
>>> d
{'red': 18, 'blue': 5}
>>> d['blue']
5
>>> d['red']
18
>>> d['red'] = 8
>>> d
{'red': 26, 'blue': 5}
```

EDIT: I see you changed the initial object...

```
>>> mydict = [{"red":6}, {"blue":5}, {"red":12}]
>>> sum(d.get('red', 0) for d in mydict)
18
```

Answer (score 1):

you cannot have a dictionary with same keys....
For definition keys are unique!
and the last assignement of a key, overwrite the previous one