# Python dictionary; sum values of the same keys

Tags: python, dictionary

It might be simple but I'm just a beginner.
If I have this dictionary;

```
ds = {"ABab": 6.25, "aBab": 6.25, "Abab": 6.25, "abab": 6.25, "ABab": 6.25, "aBab": 6.25, "Abab": 6.25, "abab": 6.25, "ABab": 6.25, "aBab": 6.25, "Abab": 6.25, "abab": 6.25, "ABab": 6.25, "aBab": 6.25, "Abab": 6.25, "abab": 6.25}
```

is there a way to create this?:

```
ds_new = {"ABab": 25, "aBab": 25, "Abab": 25, "abab": 25}
```

If there is no way to do this, thank you for looking into it anyway.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to have two or more keys with the same name in a dictionary in python. Keys should have a unique name.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21518271/how-to-sum-values-of-the-same-key-in-a-dictionary however I really do not like the accepted answer..

Comment: If you compile the first line and then "print ds" you get {'ABab': 6.25, 'aBab': 6.25, 'Abab': 6.25, 'abab': 6.25}

Answer (score 3):

As noted already, you can't store this data in a dictionary. You could store it in some other form such as a list of tuples.

```
ds = [("ABab", 6.25), ("aBab", 6.25), ("Abab", 6.25), ("abab", 6.25),
      ("ABab", 6.25), ("aBab", 6.25), ("Abab", 6.25), ("abab", 6.25),
      ("ABab", 6.25), ("aBab", 6.25), ("Abab", 6.25), ("abab", 6.25),
      ("ABab", 6.25), ("aBab", 6.25), ("Abab", 6.25), ("abab", 6.25)]
```

Then you can make a dictionary of the totals by first finding the unique keys and then summing the values of the tuples which have that key as their first value.

```
keys = set(k for k, _ in ds)
totals = {unique_key: sum(v for k, v in ds if k==unique_key) 
    for unique_key in keys}
```

Or another way (probably better)

```
totals = {}
for key, value in ds:
    totals[key] = totals.get(key, 0) + value
```

Comment: or use `totals = collections.defaultdict(int)` and sum with `+=`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have the same key twice in python. Every key in the dictionary must be unique. Review the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#dict):

> If a key occurs more than once, the last value for that key becomes the corresponding value in the new dictionary.

Your dictionary is automaticity not regarding the duplicate keys, it will always evaluate the last assigned key.

```
duplicate_keys = {"ABab": 6.25, "aBab": 6.25, "Abab": 6.25, "abab": 6.25, "ABab": 6.25, "aBab": 6.25, "Abab": 6.25, "abab": 6.25, "ABab": 6.25, "aBab": 6.25, "Abab": 6.25, "abab": 6.25, "ABab": 6.25, "aBab": 6.25, "Abab": 6.25, "abab": 6.25}

unique_keys = {"ABab": 6.25, "aBab": 6.25, "Abab": 6.25, "abab": 6.25}

duplicate_keys == unique_keys # True
```