# Extend a dict with anoter dict with cumulative values result

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, dictionary

I want to extend a given dict with another but if a key is already existing I must accumulate the values.

Example:

Let's consider a given function called cumulative_update and two dicts a and b:

```
a = { "a" : 1, "b" : 2, "c" : 1 }
b = { "c" : 3, "d" : 4 }
a.cumulative_update(b)
```

The result wanted should be:

> {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 4, 'd': 4}

But, when I use the default append function:

```
a.update(b)
```

I get:

> {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}

I found also a solution to append values in [How to sum values of the same key in a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21518271/how-to-sum-values-of-the-same-key-in-a-dictionary) but it is based on keys which isn't possible in my case.

Comment: This is where [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) really shines: [example](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-add-values-from-two-dictionaries-in-python).

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-combine-two-dictionary-adding-values-for-common-keys/

This can be a good read. Please check the solutions

Comment: Yes, very good, we can use counter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

a = { "a" : 1, "b" : 2, "c" : 1 }
b = { "c" : 3, "d" : 4 }

result = Counter(a) + Counter(b)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Counter({'c': 4, 'd': 4, 'b': 2, 'a': 1})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = { "a" : 1, "b" : 2, "c" : 1 }
b = { "c" : 3, "d" : 4 }


result = {key: a.get(key, 0) + b.get(key, 0) for key in set(a) | set(b)}
```

Output:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 4, 'c': 4}
```